# How to skip over cells in excel that meet a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel with two main columns. One column has all students the other column has the corresponding z-scores.

In a report format, I would like to make a new table of only students who's z-scores < -1.

What I have so far is as follows:

```
=(INDEX(IF(F8:F37<-1,B8:B37,)))
```

This does exactly what I want; however, it leaves cells blank when students scores are not < -1. What I want it to do is to print the student name only if the condition is met and not make an empty cell at all. The desired outcome would look something like this:

```
| Name      | z-score |   | Report of students 1 SD below average |
|-----------|---------|---|---------------------------------------|
| Student 1 | -1.65   |   | Student 1                             |
| Student 2 | 0.42    |   | Student 3                             |
| Student 3 | -1.02   |   |                                       |
| Student 4 | 0.89    |   |                                       |
| Student 5 | 1.03    |   |                                       |
```

I am currently getting something similar to this:

```
| Name      | z-score |   | Report of students 1 SD below average |
|-----------|---------|---|---------------------------------------|
| Student 1 | -1.65   |   | Student 1                             |
| Student 2 | 0.42    |   |                                       |
| Student 3 | -1.02   |   | Student 3                             |
| Student 4 | 0.89    |   |                                       |
| Student 5 | 1.03    |   |                                       |
```

Comment: Please also share some sample data with expected output. You can use this [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to generate the data table and post it here.

Comment: And you do want to do so through formula? If so you might want to look into SMALL

Comment: I was attempting to do this with formulas but if there is a better way I would be interested in learning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Supposing that the report row it is matching with the first row used.

`=IF(SMALL($F$8:$F$37,ROW()-7)<-1, VLOOKUP(SMALL($F$8:$F$37,ROW()-7),CHOOSE({2\1},$B$8:$B$37,$F$8:$F$37),2,FALSE),"")`

This formula it is checking if the values (from the smallest one to the bigger one) are minor than -1. If it is the case, it will search for the smallest value row and will return the name. On the next row, it will take the second smallest value...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the help. I used the function you gave me but it seems to have a small problem in it. It is yielding an error message. Does it work in your file?

Comment: Yes it works in the same position of your files. I supposed that the first riw of the report is matching with the first row of your range. It is just checking first if the first smallest item is less than -1, if it is the case, it is takimg the smallest value and searching on column B. Once you drag that down, it will go for the next smaller element and so on... Until you reach values greater than -1

Comment: I understand it needs to be at the same row as the original data (else I should change 7). I'm still getting an error. In excel when I try to enter this it shows a pop-up asking if I am meaning to write a formal. I tried in google sheets as well and it shows "Error - Formula parse error." I understand the flow of the formula but I am confused why in the choose function the index value is {2\1}.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Sorry for being difficult.

Comment: The 2/1 is the order sequence. As we are trying to lookup one value that is at the left side of another one. So we are placing on the formula columns B and F an it is considering F as first and B as second. VLOOKUP cannot search on the left. Don't worry

Comment: I already check the formula and it works. Could you send me your Excel file or just one sample? davidbodego@gmail.com